# How to pluralize a name in a template with jinja2?

Tags: python, templates, jinja2, pluralize

If I have a template variable called num_countries, to pluralize with Django I could just write something like this:

```
countr{{ num_countries|pluralize:"y,ies" }}
```

Is there a way to do something like this with jinja2? (I do know this doesn't work in jinja2) What's the jinja2 alternative to this?

Thanks for any tip!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to Jinja's documentation, there is no [built in filter](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#list-of-builtin-filters) which does what you want. You can easily design a [custom filter](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/api/#writing-filters) to do that, however:

```
def my_plural(str, end_ptr = None, rep_ptr = ""):
    if end_ptr and str.endswith(end_ptr):
        return str[:-1*len(end_ptr)]+rep_ptr
    else:
        return str+'s'
```

and then register it in your environment:

```
environment.filters['myplural'] = my_plural
```

You can now use my_plural as a Jinja template.

Answer (score 35):

Guy Adini's reply is definitely the way to go, though I think (or maybe I misused it) it is not exactly the same as *pluralize* filter in Django.

Hence this was my implementation (using decorator to register)

```
@app.template_filter('pluralize')
def pluralize(number, singular = '', plural = 's'):
    if number == 1:
        return singular
    else:
        return plural
```

This way, it is used exactly the same way (well, with parameters being passed in a slightly different way):

```
countr{{ num_countries|pluralize:("y","ies") }}
```

Comment: It seems that there's no need for semicolon when using a custom filter with arguments. At least there's no hint for it in jinja2's v.2.8 [documentation](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/api/#writing-filters). I guess your example should be fixed like this: `countr{{ num_countries|pluralize("y","ies") }}`

Comment: 21, 31, 41 country, 11 countries

Comment: I would use `number % 100 in {1,21,31,41,51,61,71,81,91}`

Comment: In English, you definitely write '41 countries'.

Answer (score 17):

Current Jinja versions have the [i18n extension](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#i18n) which adds decent translation and pluralization tags:

```
{% trans count=list|length %}
There is {{ count }} {{ name }} object.
{% pluralize %}
There are {{ count }} {{ name }} objects.
{% endtrans %}
```

You can use this even if you don't actually have multiple language versions - and if you ever add other languages you'll have a decent base which requires no changes (not all languages pluralize by adding an 's' and some even have multiple plural forms).

Answer (score -6):

You also want to check if the word is already plural. Here is my solution:

```
def pluralize(text):
    if text[-1:] !='s':
        return text+'s'
    else: 
        return text
```

Then register the tag to your environment (this can be applied to the Django templating engine too).